# Use of subscript cc for HCl and H2SO4

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, notation

Does the subscript $\ce{X}_{cc}$ mean *concentrated*? I have never seen this notation. How often is it used and what are the general guidelines to denoting concentrated reagents?

Comment: It is unusual to me. Could you link a reference, or show a picture of it being used?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe-srv/pdbechem/chemicalCompound/show/XCC) link possibly relevant.  It's a long shot for sure, but this has me pretty stumped. In the link it basically uses Xcc where cc means "C Cluster".  I still have no idea what the first C means even in this context.

Comment: A professor used it in a lecture and I'm quite sure he meant concentrated by it. So, it is not really a part of common usage?

Answer (score 4):

I found a very old [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=vYMdAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA482&lpg=PA482&dq=x_cc+chemistry&source=bl&ots=OkMiJVmqAC&sig=lDIAFM3nD0XYRxtVWt8YTAvDVcs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL2c2l5PDSAhWCxYMKHXm9Dh4Q6AEIHjAI#v=onepage&q=x_cc%20chemistry&f=false) that used this notation to describe a plot where $X$ many cubic centimeters of $\ce{HCl}$ are added to a solution.

Comment: That would be my guess as well, but in general I think it would mean the concentration in mass per cc